# how to pass a property from parent template to slot in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a component A which wraps the component B using slot

**component-A declaration**

```
<component-A>
     <slot></slot>
</component-A>
```

**component-B Usage:**

```
   <component-A :some-prop="foo">
      <component-B></component-B>
   </component-A>
```

when i pass this prop (someProp) to component-A, is there any way to access it in component-B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to share information between the father and whatever have in your slot, Vue offers a slot props propertie, something like this:

```
<slot name="icon-order" :someProp="some-prop" :someProp2="some-prop2">
```

Once you inject something on component slot, you'll be able to access that propertie like:

```
<component-A :some-prop="foo">
     <component-B slot-scope="slotProps"></component-B>
</component-A>
```

Then, inside component-B you'll have access to slotProps with every declared propertie set on component-A, just use: slotProps.someProp or slotProps.someProp2.

You can have a better look at Vue documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

hope that helps

Comment: Pleasure to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `component-B` needs to be passed some data, then it must receive it through a prop.

What you're asking is for `component-B` to also receive `foo`; just pass it via a prop in the same way you did for `component-A`, the slotting here makes no difference.

```vue
<component-A :some-prop="foo">
  <component-B :some-prop="foo"></component-B>
</component-A>
```

However I suspect this isn't exactly your issue; if not please clarify how the slotting here is relevant.

Comment: i am new to vuejs, i did slotting because it would accept dynamic components.

Comment: the component -A is kind of hide or show the wrapped component B, in usage there may be many other components present in place of B, but they share a common data source